# Dynamic forms in Django hosted by GAE

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms

I am a newbie to Django, GAE, and met some problems when I am trying to build some dynamic forms using Django. The idea is that the selection made from one drop-down box determines value in another field.

In detail, if an user

1. choose "A" in "Species", then the value in the "body_weight" will be 178. Similarly,
2. if he choose "B" in "Species", the value in "body_weight" is 1580, and
3. if choose "C" in "Species", the he can fill in the "body_weight"

I read some examples, and found some features like "init, and super should be included". Thus I modified my codes, but it still did not work.

My problems are:

1. What is the right position to place "*init*" and "super"?
2. Do I need "self.field" here?

All suggestions are welcomed!

Thanks!

Here is the code.

```
Species_CHOICES=(('178','A'),('1580','B'),('','C'))

class Inp(forms.Form):
    Species = forms.ChoiceField(label='Species', choices=Species_CHOICES, initial='A')

    #Here detect the choice made by the user
    def get_STB_choices(Species):
        if Species=='178':
            r= 178
        elif Species=='1580':
            r= 1580
        else:
            r= 4440
        return a

    #assign values to a new parameter based on user's choice 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Inp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
    body_weight=forms.FloatField(required=True, label='Body weight', initial=get_STB_choices(Species))


#write out in HTML
class InputPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        html = str(Inp())
self.response.out.write(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need Javascript running on the page to update the available selections.

I implemented it one way here.  Each time you make a selection, the page makes an AJAX request to get the new form fields that were dependent on the initial change.

https://github.com/dragonx/django-hier-ajax-form

After I did mine, I realized there was already an existing project that did the same thing, but our implementations are pretty different:

https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

btw, I believe usually when you call super() you use it with the name of the current class, so I would have expected

```
super(Inp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but can this be finished without importing Ajax?

Comment: I believe thong's question is simpler than this: Given one of several possible user inputs, how do you store a different corresponding value (not the input itself) in the model, using Django forms?

Comment: @Dan Sanderson, you are right. My purpose is to save and show(which requires instantly webpage refresh) two inputs, the first one comes from the user's selection, and the other depending on the previous one. In the future, I will send those inputs to a cloud based SQL. So suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Even if you don't use AJAX to pull up new values, you'll still need Javascript to update the page dynamically.

Comment: You can update the form's save() function to save the new values based on the input.  But without Javascript, you can't update the webpage as you enter data.

Comment: @dragonx, so it seems like the solution to refreshing webpage based on user selection is to add Javascript?

Comment: Yes, use an event handler on the first select field to update the choice on the second select field.  This shouldn't be too hard if you use something like jQuery to help you out.  There's probably tutorials online for that too.