# Display Selection from Django choicefield?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-forms

Is there a way to display the selection in Django choicefield? For example, I would like to 
display the selected choice in "S". Is there an easy way to do this(build-in function)?

```
S_CHOICES=(('A','A'),('B','B'),('Other','Other'))
S = forms.ChoiceField(choices=select_CHOICES, initial='A')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self['S'].value()
print(S)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in form's `__init__`:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    S_CHOICES=(('A','A'),('B','B'),('Other','Other'))
    S = forms.ChoiceField(choices=select_CHOICES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['S'].initial = 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this. However, my website is built on GAE which just use Django to create forms for inputs (does not have view.py). So is there a way to display selection in my case?

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I have found the _init_ might help. But based on your code, when I printed S, it is a memory address "<django.forms.fields.ChoiceField object at 0x05DD0290>", not 'A'. Did I do something wrong? Thanks again for your patient.

Comment: @thong Why do you need to print it? You need to render it in template? Or you need to get its value?

Comment: Since my whole idea is to create a dynamic drop-down cell (a choicefield), whose results control another cell. Thus, I need to compare selection made from this choicefield to some critical values. However, I found that I could not directly compare a choicefield to a string or value. As a result, I created this post. Do you have any suggestion on this issue? Details are listed in this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728972/dynamic-forms-in-django-hosted-by-gae

Comment: @thong If you want a value of field use `self.cleaned_data['S']` (after validation) or `self['S'].value()` (before validation) inside the form class. Is this what you need?

Comment: I tried both ways, but it seems does not work. Would you mind taking a look at the edited code, and let me know my problem? Thanks!